# Why can I not use the "<<" operator in a return statement?

Tags: c++, operators, return, stringstream

For instance:

```
std::stringstream formatMemUsage(...) {
    std::stringstream ss ...
    ...
    return ss << "MB";   // Error here
}
```

results in the the error `no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>" to "std::stringstream" exists`.

I *can* separate the return statement into 2 statements `ss << "MB"; return ss;` and the error disappears - why?

(Using MSVC++ 2010)

Comment: `<<` is overloaded in stringstream to return `ostream&`. try casting.

Comment: You can. Use inheritance properly and return `std::ostream&`!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: He can't as that would lead to returning a reference to a local object!

Comment: @MFH: He should pass a reference to a stream as an argument to the function, or return a `std::string`. Streams are not copyable. They are not containers, but _flows of data_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: IMHO that greatly depends on what you want to do... And as I said streams are moveable so no copying is required.

Comment: @MFH: It is true that C++11 may change this somewhat. Still, though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are returning the last evaluated statement. Consider what this is actually doing:

```
return ss << "MB";
```

Is equivalent to:

```
return operator<<(ss, "MB");
```

The return type of `operator<<` in this case is, as you've seen, `std::ostream&` - not a `std::stringstream` as you wanted.

Comment: Even if the types matched, streams are not copyable. And the return type is `std::ostream&`.

Comment: I'm still completely baffled about how this "sorted" OP problem. His/hers code is not valid.

Comment: @jrok "sorted" with respect to the original error, not about the streams not being copyable. I guess I'll just try and return a string instead.

Comment: FWIW - you can simply cast it back to the real type... `return static_cast<std::stringstream&>(ss << "MB");`

Comment: @Angew And return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: @JamesKanze Of course, stupid me :-( Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yes returning a string makes much more sense, unless you need to efficiently chain formatting operations, in which case pass an existing stream into this function as an argument.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If the function actually outputs significant data, the solution is to encapsulate the data in a class, and provide an `<<` operator for the class.  C++ is so much easier than plain C.

Comment: @James: Yeah or that. Doesn't seem appropriate in this case, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hard to say, because we don't really know the problem he's trying to solve.

Comment: @James: I dunno.. the question seems pretty clear. There's a numeric input representing number of bytes of memory used, and it's getting formatted into a human-readable string.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit From the name of the function, I'd tend to agree with you.  On the other hand, it might make more sense to wrap the thing in a class and define an `operator<<` for it.  A lot depends on what's really in place of those ..., and what is going on at the call site.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.  The first is, as Yuushi points out,
that the type of the expression `ss << "MB"` is `std::ostream&`,
and not `std::stringstream`, and there is no implicit conversion
from `std::ostream` to `std::stringstream`.  The second is that
streams are *not* copiable, so there is no way you can ever
return a `std::stringstream` (which would require a copy).  And
you can't simply change the return value to `std::ostream&`,
because that would result in returning a reference to a local
variable; `ss` will be destructed at the end of the function.

What are you trying to achieve?  Most of the time, just 
returning a string (`ss.str()`) would be a better solution.

Comment: Actually you can return a `stringstream` by value, as they are moveable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm currently not at a PC with VS 2010, but from what I recall it already supports move semantics for the standard library types.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can confirm that VS 2010 has some support for move semantics.  On the other hand, I doubt that using them is the right solution here.